# Error creating order with Python API: "\"products\" is not a mapping type

Tags: planet

I am getting the following error when I try to place a Planet Labs order through the Python API as described at https://www.planet.com/docs/referencev0/orders/:

`{"message": "Request validation failed", "errors": [{"field": "data", "message": "\"products\" is not a mapping type: Does not implement dict-like functionality."}]}`

I am using the following Python code.

```
import requests
import os

SESSION = requests.Session()
SESSION.auth = (os.environ['PL_API_KEY'], '')

payload = {
  "type": "download",
  "data": {
    "products": [
      {
        "scene_name": "20150420_141621_081c",
        "product_type": "visual",
        "provider": "ortho"
      },
      {
        "scene_name": "20150420_141621_081c",
        "product_type": "analytic",
        "provider": "ortho"
      }
    ]
  }
}

r = SESSION.post("https://api.planet.com/v0/orders/", data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

What am I doing wrong?